# Some special closed sets in the Bohr compactification of the reals

Tags: gn.general-topology, harmonic-analysis

Let $X$ denote the Bohr compactification of the reals.  What can be said about the intersection of $\overline{\mathbb R^+}^X$ 
with $\overline{\mathbb R^-}^X$, the closures in $X$  of $\mathbb R^+:=\{x\in\mathbb R: x\geq 0\}$ and $\mathbb R^-=\{x\in\mathbb R: x\leq 0\}$.
Is this bigger than $\{0\}$?

Answer (score 4):

The intersection is $X$. (Both $\mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R^-$ are dense *in* $X$.)

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $(X \setminus \mathbb{R}) \cup \{0\}$? If I understand correctly, no point of $\mathbb{R}^+$ can be in the $X$-closure of $\mathbb{R}^-$, and vice versa?

Comment: No, I meant it as written. Every point of $X$ (hence in particular of $\mathbb R^+$) is in the $X$-closure of $\mathbb R^-$.

Comment: Thanks, got it. (In case anyone gets confused, as I did: the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ is not the same as the subspace topology inherited from $X$.)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: This short answer completely replaces a previous one.

---

Francois Ziegler had already answered correctly. 
This is just to note the following general fact: every closed subsemigroup of a compact group is a group.

Let me sketch the proof of this fact.
Let $G$ be a compact group and $1\in G$ its unit element.
Let $S\subset G$ be a closed semigroup.
First observe that 1 is contained in every closed right ideal $I$ of $S$
(right ideal means: for $i\in I$ and $s\in S$ we have $is\in I$).
Indeed, by Zorn + compactness $I$ contains a minimal closed right ideal of $S$, $J$, and for $j\in J$, $jJ=J\ni j$, thus $1\in J$.
Now, for every $s\in S$, $sS$ is a closed right ideal of $S$, thus $1\in sS$, thus $s^{-1}\in S$. We conclude that $S$ is a group.

Comment: Why is it immediately clear that $f(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is the preimage of $g(\mathbb{R}^+)$ under $\pi$ (and not merely a subset of this preimage)?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, I was sloppy. I replaced what I wrote with a general observation.

Comment: What is meaning of a "right ideal of $G$" here, and in what sense is $\{1\}$ a right ideal in a nontrivial group? (I'm not doubting the "general fact", and I know the proof using idempotents in compact semigroups--I'm just not following this particular argument.)

Comment: @GabeConant, thanks for the comment. I made an edit. I tried to circumvent the structure theory of compact semigroups, exploiting having an ambient group.

Comment: Why $j\in jJ$ implies $1\in J$?

Comment: It implies $j=jg$ for some $g\in J$. Apply $j^{-1}$ from the left on both sides to see that $g=1$.